# Shortest path - let the root node point to itself

Tags: java, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I am implementing a shortest path algorithm using a linked list. Once the algorithm finds its target I want to trace backwards through the list. Is there any reason I shouldn't make the root node point to itself as a way to test for its "rootness" I.e., `tracebackwards until this.node = parent.node`? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally favor the idea that the root node has no parent node (as it is the root and has no logical parent). So within this context it makes sense to use null as the value for the parent.node of the root node.

Tracing back would come down to looping until the parent.node == null